# Access data sent from stringRequest

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio, android-volley

I am trying to access data sent from stringRequest here:

```
public class ProductDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String cart_url = "http://192.168.1.15/AndroidAppDatabaseConnection/add_to_cart.php";
String favorites_url = "http://192.168.1.15/AndroidAppDatabaseConnection/add_to_favorites.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_detail);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
    String email = intent.getStringExtra("user");
    final int product_id = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, 0);
    String name = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME);
    Double price = intent.getDoubleExtra(EXTRA_PRICE, 0);
    String description = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DESCRIPTION);
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView textViewName = findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
    TextView textViewPrice = findViewById(R.id.text_view_price);
    TextView textViewDescription = findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
    Button add_cart = findViewById(R.id.add_cart);
    Button add_favorites = findViewById(R.id.add_wishlist);
    add_cart.setTag(email);
    textViewName.setText(name);
    textViewPrice.setText(price + "€");
    textViewDescription.setText(description);
    add_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = view.getTag().toString();
            add_to_cart(email, product_id);
        }
    });
    add_favorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            add_to_favorites();
        }
    });
}
private void add_to_cart(final String e, final int id) {
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonBody.put("user", e);
        jsonBody.put("product", id);
        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, cart_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
            Toast.makeText(ProductDetailActivity.this,"successfully Add Into Cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(ProductDetailActivity.this, "Could not add item into cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user", e);
            params.put("product", String.valueOf(id));
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void add_to_favorites() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, favorites_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(ProductDetailActivity.this, "Successfully added into Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(ProductDetailActivity.this, "Could not add item into favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };
   RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

And here I try to access the data in my PHP file:

```
<?php
include_once "database_connect.php";
$email = $_POST["user"];
$product_id = $_POST["product"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email';";
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_id = $row['user_id'];
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count>0){ /*if product is already in cart */
    echo "Product already in cart";
}
else {
    $add_to_cart="INSERT INTO cart (user_id,product_id,quantity) VALUES ('$user_id','$product_id','1')";
    if(!mysqli_query($conn,$add_to_cart))
    {
        echo "Can't add product to cart";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Product successfully added to cart";
    }
}
```

What happens is that the query is successfully run but inserts 0 both on user_id and product_id positions.

What Am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your query (which is open to SQL injections) has no relation to items in the cart. So `if($count>0){ /*if product is already in cart */` is incorrect.

Comment: Did you end up solving your problem?

Comment: I actually did @Ivan86, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of SQL injection! Use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php//php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to protect your database.

---

To check if a product is already in the cart for a particular user you could change your first sql query to something like this (written as a prepared statement):

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT c.quantity FROM cart c
                       JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.user_id
                       WHERE c.product_id = ? AND u.email = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("is", $product_id, $email);
// 'i' means integer and 's' means string
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    // product exists in cart
}

$stmt->close();
```